# How to prove $n! > n^k$ and $\lim(n^k/n!) = 0$

Tags: limits, inequality

Any ideas how to prove that:

$$n! > n^k$$

And what about proving this limit:

$$\lim\left(\frac{n^k}{n!}\right) = 0$$

Thanks!

In addition: Is there a way to prove $n! > n^k$ without using limit. By induction or by another way.

Comment: $\frac{(n+1)^k}{(n+1)!} = \frac{(n+1)^{k-1}}{n!} \sim \frac{n^{k-1}}{n!}$ as $n\to \infty$ and so you can procede by induction on $k$ to answer the second question. The first question is an easy consequence on the second one (of course the inequality only holds for sufficiently large $n$)

Comment: $k=5$, $n=2$, then your inequality do not hold. You should modify the question like this: for a given $k>0$ , $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $n!>n^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much stuff to put in a comment, but I wanted to go over how you could show $n! > n^k$ eventually, without using a limit argument. I show a bound of $n \ge k^2 + 1 \implies n! > n^k$.

Suppose first that $k \ge 2$ is an integer and $n = k^2 + 1$. Note that $(k^2 + 1)!$ contains factors $k, k + 1, k + 2, \ldots k^2, k^2 + 1$, all of which are at least $k$, and numbering $k^2 - k + 2$. Since the last two are at least $k^2$, we can say $(k^2)! \ge k^{k^2 - k + 4}$. To show this is greater than $(k^2 + 1)^k < (k^3)^k = k^{3k}$, it suffices to show that $k^2 - k + 4 \ge 3k$, which is true as it is equivalent to $(k - 2)^2 \ge 0$.

Still assuming $k \ge 2$ is an integer, we can show the rest by induction. Specifically, if we assume some particular $n \ge k^2 + 1$ has the property $n! > n^k$, then

$$(n + 1)! = (n + 1)n! > (n + 1)n^k = n^{k+1} + n^k > n^{k+1},$$

so the $n! > n^k$ for $n \ge k^2 + 1$.

Now, if $k < 2$, note that $n^k < n^2 < n!$ for $n \ge 2^2 + 1 = 5$. If $k > 2$, but is not an integer, round it up to the next integer.

Answer (score 3):

For $n\ge k+2$, 
$$n!\ge n(n-1)\ldots (n-k)(n-k-1)=n^{k+1}\left({1-\frac1n}\right)\ldots \left({1-\frac{k+1}n}\right).$$
So $$\frac{n!}{n^k}\ge n\left({1-\frac1n}\right)\ldots \left({1-\frac{k+1}n}\right)\to \infty\left({1-0}\right)\ldots \left({1-0}\right)$$
as $n\to\infty$, 
where you used the fact that there were only $k$ terms in the product and $k$ is fixed. In particular $n!>n^k$ for all $n$ large.

In turn, $\frac{n^k}{n!}\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

All will follow from
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^k}{n!}=0
$$
that can be inferred from the fact that the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{n!}
$$
passes the ratio test for convergence: indeed
$$
\frac{(n+1)^k/(n+1)!}{n^k/n!}
=\frac{(n+1)^k}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{n^k}
=\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k
$$
has limit $0$ for $n\to\infty$.

Therefore there exists $N$ such that, for $n>N$,
$$
\frac{n^k}{n!}<1
$$

Comment: Is there a way to prove $n!>n^k$ without using limit?

Comment: @GusevSlava Yes, of course there is. You find it in the other answers.